# How to make drag and drop in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a list of buttons and gameobject cube.
I need to drag one button on cube and cube will be destroyed. If the name of my button is cube and i drag it on cube, cube will be destroyed, but if the name is sphere and i drag this button on cube, cube will not be destroyed.
How to do this?

Comment: Mind to share some code you tried or are using?

Answer (score 1):

The information you give is too little to accurately answer your question.

But I can give you a pointer to the documentation about the script object you would need to get started
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IDragHandler.html